# Is it necessary to duplicate object when adding it to a listener queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, mutex

Here is the situation:

I'm handling packets received through a socket `Connection` and each packet has a distinct ID and an associated subclass of a general class `Message` (so `FooMessage`, `BarMessage`, `HelloMessage`).

I need to use these messages to update some information in the program (information is stored in different classes, like `AInformation` concerning everything related to `A` kind a things, `BInformation` things related to `B` kind of things, `CInformation` and so on...).

To do this, I introduced a third party: a `Listener` that listens to some particular types of messages and uses them to update the Information class associated to the `Listener`. So we have `AListener` that handles `FooMessage` and `BarMessage`, has some particular functions that update `AInformation`, `BListener` that handles `BarMessage` and `HelloMessage` and update `BInformation`...

Here is the life cycle of a `Message` that comes through my socket connection:

1. `DuhMessage` is created by the `Connection` from a `Packet` (byte array)
2. `DuhMessage` is sent to all the listeners by the `Connection` (**I'll explain my implementation of this step, which is the problem for me**)
3. Each listener looks at `DuhMessage` and, if it is interesting to update the kind of information the listener is dealing with, the message is handled by a function

#### **Step 2:**

To take care of step **2**, I basically have a list of `Listener`s in my `Connection` (this list has to be thread-safe since a `Listener` can be added to the `Connection`'s list anytime). `Connection` locks the list and push `DuhMessage` to all the `Listener`s queue of messages. (`Listener` has a queue of messages and it consumes them one after another, updating the `Information` class)

Here is a schema I made with Dia that sums it up:

[image]

My question is:

**When I push `DuhMessage` to the `Listener`'s queue, should I duplicate the object? Because my `Listener`s could try to read the `DuhMessage`'s attributes in the same time, couldn't they?**

Here is my thread-safe deque implementation I made for this situation (if you could validate it).

```
#include <deque>
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include "network/message.h"
#include "network/listener.h"
#include "utils/datastruct/listener_deque.h"


#ifndef LISTENER_DEQUE_H
#define LISTENER_DEQUE_H

/**
 * Thread-Safe listener deque. Allow to add listeners and send messages to
 * listeners
 */
class ListenerDeque
{
public:
    ListenerDeque ();
    virtual ~ListenerDeque ();

    /**
     * Add one listener to the deque
     */
    void push(std::shared_ptr<Listener> listener);

    /**
     * Add multiple listeners to the deque
     */
    void push(std::list<std::shared_ptr<Listener>> listeners);

    /**
     * Send a message to all listeners
     */
    void send(std::unique_ptr<Message> message);

    /**
     * Returns whether the deque is empty or not
     */
    bool empty();

    /**
     * Returns the number of listeners in the deque
     */
    int size();

private:
    std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Listener>> listeners;
    mutable boost::mutex mutex;
};

#endif

bool ListenerDeque::empty()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(this->mutex);
    return this->listeners.empty();
}


int ListenerDeque::size()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(this->mutex);
    return this->listeners.size();
}


void ListenerDeque::push(std::list<std::shared_ptr<Listener> > listeners)
{
    typedef std::list<std::shared_ptr<Listener> >::iterator iterator;
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(this->mutex);
    for (iterator it = listeners.begin(); it != listeners.end(); ++it)
        this->listeners.push_back(*it);
}


void ListenerDeque::push(std::shared_ptr<Listener> listener)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(this->mutex);
    this->listeners.push_back(listener);
}


void ListenerDeque::send(std::unique_ptr<Message> message)
{
    typedef std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Listener> >::iterator iterator;
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(this->mutex);
    for (iterator it = this->listeners.begin();
            it != this->listeners.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Message> m (message.copy());
        (*it)->push(m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If there is one-to-one association between message and listener, you can do message-to- listener qualification in single thead, moving message to proper listener, no concurrent access in this case.
2. If one message could go to multipy listeners, send them "const DuhMessage *" and they will not able to modify message attibutes in any way, so concurrent read access will be safe.
   The only problem would be who will delete DuhMessage, use ref_count etc.

Comment: Yes, a same message can go to multiple `Listener`s and "**Who is going to destroy the message?**" is the question, exactly :/ Thanks for the answer, I will look at 'ref_count' :)

Comment: Do you think I could use a shared pointers to do that instead?

Comment: I think so, but only in case you will use const pointers to restrict Listener from message modification. Obviously, const pointers are not the only way to allow concurrent read access, but the simpliest one.

Comment: `Listener` will just read `Message`'s attributes, `Listener`s are just using the information contained in the messages.

Comment: Do not know Message attrubutes type, some custom-developed containers modify internal state during navigaton. Be care of them.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be a variation of disruptor pattern (a parallelized pipeline). A single copy of the message is submitted to the pipeline backed by a fixed size thread pool.

A pipeline fragment of readonly listeners can handle message in parallel, if they need they can make a mutable copy for their own use (like writing to the database asynchronously).

A pipeline fragments: readonly->mutating, mutating->mutating, and mutating->readonly must be processed serialized.

The original message should be destroyed by the dispatcher once all listeners/handlers are done with it.

Making copying a part of the event handler will pollute its logic and impair scalability of the whole solution.

Comment: You scared me. I'm going to look at this disruptor pattern. But it looks too complex for what I am doing.

Comment: @toogy, then just start from a single thread app, make the message immutable for listeners and have them decide if they need their private copy (in which case they'll need to clone the message) or can do with readonly shared one :)

Comment: I'm going with std::shared_ptr<Message> and if I got problems I'll try another way. :p